# ERROR ITMS-90513: Missing Info.plist Key. Your app's Info.plist must contain the 'TVTopShelfImage.TVTopShelfPrimaryImageWide' key

Tags: ios, assets, apple-tv, tvos11

We are trying to upload TV OS build to app store but its always fails..Please find a error screenshots

[image: Error Image]

We tried so many possibilities but nothings helps and we are using Xcode 9 version, we added 1920X720 image also.

Restarted system also did not help.

Answer (score 7):

It was great experience to find out the solution, We don't need to add aplpha value to top shelf image but we should need two different images with sizes.

Top Shelf: 1920 x 720

Top Shelf Wide: 2320 x 720

The problem was:

I have created new App icon and launch image and its giving by default with name of **"Brand Assets"**

[image]

Then we have added all required images and tried to upload into app store finally we got this issue. To rectify this we have changed name **Brand** **Assets** into **"App Icon & Top Shelf Image"**

[image]
In general tab it was selected **App Icon & Top Shelf Image** but asset does not contain with that name.

Finally issues went away.

Answer (score 5):

Uploading a tvOS app will fail unless you provide only a single-layer top shelf image, and a single layer top shelf wide image.

Top Shelf: 1920 x 720

Top Shelf Wide: 2320 x 720

Both cannot have alpha channels or the upload will fail.

ensure once the image is properly added or its shows any warning

Comment: Beautiful answer

Comment: You mean we should  add alpha values to those images

Comment: We have added alpha values still same error throwing..Do you any sample images apple-tv app icon?

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have added my answer