# CFBundleIcons error when uploading TV OS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tvos

problem is when i am trying upload AppleTV app to AppStoreConnect it gives me this errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCNAn.png)

Cant find any information how to fix it

This is my info.plist:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUg3p.png)

Tried to change info.plist

Comment: You need to ensure that your tvOS app has icons and that you have added a top shelf image and referenced it in your info.plist. https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/top-shelf

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905747/error-itms-90513-missing-info-plist-key-your-apps-info-plist-must-contain-the

Answer (score 0):

Check Primary App Icon Set Name in build settings. It should be the same as in assets